# In the command center in x-com enemy unknown the view is stuck. How to resolve that?

Tags: pc, xcom-enemy-unknown

When I open the command center in enemy unknown, the view is stuck at always the same place. I cannot move the globe and generally don't see anything else than north america. This seems to be the case after I lost an interceptor.
Any ideas how to resolve that?

Comment: I had this happen to me before, I got out of it by hitting escape/enter a bunch of times.

Comment: I'll try that. I even restarted the computer and it is still there...

Comment: Did you by any chance send out 2 interceptors after 1 ufo, shooting it down with the first one and sending a team after it? this is a bug: http://forums.2kgames.com/showthread.php?156831-Sending-multiple-interceptors-bug-that-forces-you-to-start-over-with-new-game&p=2180831

Comment: Hm. No. First one was shot down, second attacked. Ufo got away (as far as I can remember)

Comment: @spartacus I'm afraid this did not resolve the issue.